# Template specialization and explicit specification of return type vs. auto

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the code:

```
class Test {
public:
    template<int N> auto foo() {}
    template<> auto foo<0>() { return 7;  }

    template<int N> void bar() {}
    template<> int bar<0>() { return 7;  }
};
```

I have tested the code with different compilers (through [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)).

In case of **Clang 7.0.0** `foo` compiles, while `bar` is giving an error:

> :8:20: error: no function template matches function template
>   specialization 'bar'
>
> ```
> template<> int bar<0>() { return 7;  }
>
>                ^
> ```
>
> :7:26: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'void
>   ()' against 'int ()'
>
> ```
> template<int N> void bar() {};
>
>                      ^
> ```

**Visual C++** agrees (MSVC 19 2017 RTW):

> (8): error C2912: explicit specialization 'int
>   Test::bar(void)' is not a specialization of a function template

**gcc 8.2** does not compile any of the code (though the reason is probably a [bug in C++17 support](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282):

> :5:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope
>   'class Test'
>
> ```
>  template<> auto foo<0>() { return 7;  };
>
>           ^
> ```
>
> :5:28: error: template-id 'foo<0>' in declaration of primary
>   template
>
> ```
>  template<> auto foo<0>() { return 7;  };
>
>                         ^
> ```
>
> :7:26: error: too many template-parameter-lists
>
> ```
>  template<int N> void bar() {};
>
>                       ^~~
> ```
>
> :8:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope
>   'class Test'
>
> ```
>  template<> int bar<0>() { return 7;  }
>
>           ^
> ```
>
> :8:20: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
>
> ```
>  template<> int bar<0>() { return 7;  }
>
>                 ^~~
>
>                    ;
> ```
>
> :8:23: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
>
> ```
>  template<> int bar<0>() { return 7;  }
>
>                    ^
> ```

What is the correct interpretation here? Can I have a different return type for different method specializations (and why only with `auto`, but not while specifying them explicitly)? With my limited understanding of `auto` and templates I would go with saying "no". I don't understand why would using `auto` instead of explicitly naming the return type allow to have different return type for different specializations.

However, those codes are simplified versions of the code that I have found [elsewhere](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/structured-bindings/), so maybe my interpretation is incorrect - and in that case I would be grateful for the explanation **why different return type is allowed when `auto` is used for specialization, while explicitly naming the type seems to be forbidden**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it valid to do explicit template specialisation with auto return 'type' in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629816/is-it-valid-to-do-explicit-template-specialisation-with-auto-return-type-in-c)

Comment: @DanM. The linked question does not pertain to the disparity between using `auto` and explicitly naming the return type in the specialisation.

Comment: but it does. It quotes the standard on this exact matter AFAIU: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#11 (which causes the difference in compiler behaviour).

Your example also contains this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097811/c-syntax-for-explicit-specialization-of-a-template-function-in-a-template-clas

Comment: @DanM. As far as I understand, the quoted draft says that one should use `auto` for specialization when the base template uses `auto` and one should name a concrete type when specializing a template that uses a concrete type. It is silent, as far as I can tell, on the issue of changing the return type in specialisation in any of those two cases. As for the second part of your comment (linking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097811/c): my code differs from that in that question because in my code class `Test` is not a template, what was a problem in that question.

Comment: while the example in SO question has a templated class it likewise applies to a regular one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777236 . Though it should work with c++17 and on, but GCC still doesn't support it: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282

The standard explains why `foo` is allowed. As for the error with `bar` - simply naming the function the same way as a template doesn't mean it's a specialization. You can only specialize the template parameters. `int` isn't a template parameter for `bar` (but you can make it so, in which case it should work).

Comment: @DanM. Yes, the error you gave is not a problem in C++17. I must admit I don't understand the part of your comment that starts with "You can only specialize...". If you try the following declarations of `bar` with the same return types (i.e.  `template<int N> int bar() { return 5; }
template<> int bar<0>() { return  7; }` everything compiles with `bar<42>()` returning 5 and `bar<0>()` returning 7. And I still don't  see a connection with the question you marked as a duplicate.

Comment: The linked question explains "why different return type is allowed when auto is used for specialization" part of the question. The "while explicitly naming the type seems to be forbidden." part is misguided. You are not explicitly naming a type. You are declaring `template<int N> void bar() {}` template with `N` parameter. When you write `template<> int bar<0>() { return 7;  }` you are trying to specialize `template<int N> int bar()` template which wasn't declared. Which is what the clang/VC compilers try to tell you in the error messages. I.e. see similar stackoverflow.com/questions/48489014/

Comment: @DanM. Thank you. It's getting clearer. Can I have a template specialisation with explicitly declared return type different from the base template at all? Or is a return type disparity allowed only when `auto` is used? By the way, I'd suggest collecting everything you said in a comments and answering this question with that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different problems with the example code.

1) GCC fails to implement CWG 727 (required in C++17): https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282 which causes `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Test'`

2) If we ignore that, the example code can be simplified to just

```
template<int N> auto foo() {}
template<> auto foo<0>() { return 7; }

template<int N> void bar() {}
template<> int bar<0>() { return 7; }
```

which still exhibits the same errors. Now all compilers agree on the output. They compile `foo`s and error out on the `bar` specialization.

> why different return type is allowed when auto is used for specialization

It is allowed by a standard to specialize functions with `auto` return type if the specializations also have `auto` placeholder

> Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type shall also use that placeholder, not a deduced type

http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#11

So by virtue of this specialization conforming to the standard (being similar to one of the given examples) and not being explicitly forbidden anywhere it's allowed.

As for the error with `bar`, the standard says that return type is a part of function template signature:

> ⟨function template⟩ name, parameter type list ([dcl.fct]), enclosing namespace (if any), **return type**, template-head, and trailing requires-clause ([dcl.decl]) (if any)

http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.signature.templ

As such, in compiler's eyes `template<> int bar<0>() { return 7; }` is a specialization of `template<... N> int bar();` template (notice the return type). But it wasn't declared previously (specialization can't precede declaration) so compilation fails! If you add `template<int N> int bar();` then it'll compile (but complain about call ambiguity if you try to call `bar`).

Basically, you can't change the function signature in a specialization, you can only specialize (duh) template parameters (which should also be exactly the same as in declaration, since it's also part of the signature).

> Can I have a template specialization with explicitly declared return type different from the base template at all

As explained - you can't change the function template signature which means you can't change the return type. BUT, you can specialize the return type if it depends on a template parameter!

Consider

```
template<int N, typename R = void> R bar() {}
template<> int bar<0>() { return 7; }
// bar<0, int> is deduced, see: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#10
```

This is allowed but it has a disadvantage of having to write `bar<0, int>` when you want to make a call to a specialization: https://godbolt.org/z/4lrL62

This can be worked around by making the type conditional in the original declaration: https://godbolt.org/z/i2aQ5Z

But it'll quickly become cumbersome to maintain once the number of specializations grows.

Another, perhaps a bit more maintainable option, would be to return something like `ret_type<N>::type` and specialize that along with `bar`. But it's still won't be as clean as with just using `auto`.